# Converting SQL Python database into a class

Tags: python, database, sqlite, class, for-loop

I have created this employee database for my project and need to convert it to a class (I get more marks for including classes) but I need to iterate through each column (`ID`, `name`, `jobRole`, etc.) and create an object of the `Employee` class I have created.

This is my code so far:

```
tableID = c.execute('select employeeID from employeeData')
for r in tableID:
    tableName = c.execute('select employeeName from employeeData')
    for s in tableName:
        tableJobRole = c.execute('select employeeJobRole from employeeData')
        for t in tableJobRole:
            tableYearlySalary = c.execute('select employeeYearlySalary from employeeData')
            for u in tableYearlySalary:
                v = s
                exec(str(v))
                v = Employee(r, s, t, u)
```

When I run the code in my GUI and click a button, it doesn't do what I want it to do. How would I go about creating a bit of code to iterate through the first row, setting the data in the columns to `r`, `s`, `t` and `u`, and then going onto the next row for all of them at the same time?

Each of `r`,`s`,`t`,`u` would equal the first row, then I want all of them to be equal to the next row instead of the first three staying on the first row and `u` going onto the next row until `t` is incremented then `s`.

So I'd want to somehow increment each 'for each in ...' by one at the same time somehow.

Comment: This question is very unclear. If you're looking for a general solution for representing your database schema in terms of Python classes, the [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) ORM library might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single query to return all fields for each row of the table. Try this:

```
employees = []
c.execute('select employeeID, employeeName, employeeJobRole, employeeYearlySalary from employeeData')
results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
    employees.append(Employee(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))
```

Comment: thanks! I'll try it out and will tell you how i do :)

Comment: It worked. I can't seem to be able to insert the code though... When I press enter it just submits the comment. Thanks for you time and help. Appreciate it!